# Lag when changing scene in Unity

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

I inherited a project in Unity which has a lag problem **when changing scenes**. On the Unity editor it's about 500 milliseconds but on a device it can take up to 2-3 seconds to change scene.
I *suspect* that one of the problem might be the audio files which are played every time a button is pressed. I tried disabling some components but I never worked with audio files on Unity and so I don't really know what I am doing.

This is the profiler screen (sorry for the green tint):

[image]

1. How can I find if the problem area actually the audio files?
2. Can you spot something from my profiler image?
3. I read that audio files should stay in the Streaming Assets folder but on this project they are stored on a general "Audio" folder. Is this correct?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly a combination of reading the new scene from disk and garbage collecting the old scene.

Comment: @Carcigenicate When in Play Mode, people use it to remind them that they are in Play Mode so that when they change something, they won't forget to copy and save it before exiting Play Mode. You will lose your modified data if you don't do this.

Comment: @Programmer Ahh, interesting.

Comment: @Draco18s thank you. Any idea on how to optimize that process of loading/unloading the scene?

Comment: I don't use scenes. :D